# Is there a map of the underthing?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle, patrick-rothfuss, the-slow-regard-of-silent-things

Whilst reading the kingkiller chronicles novella 'The slow regard of silent things'  I found it quite hard to mentally map out  where everything was situated in the underthing. I was reading on my kindle so I apologise if there was a map tucked in the physical copy but I'll accept a scan straight away!

I'm not looking for a direct Patrick map or even one directly from out of the book. The minimum I will accept is a fan drawn map that has sources for its design, a list of the quotes used to design such a map would suffice.

*A really super special user might craft their own map*

**Disclaimer: I know there are a lot of underthing maps out there on the internet but I'm looking for a verifiable one, one with sources similar to those mentioned above**

Comment: There's no map inside the book, and Auri's viewpoint isn't really concerned with cartography.  Most I can find is a bunch of room-connected-to-room maps that look like something out of an old Zork guide.  Which while amusingly in theme, isn't what you want, but I'm not certain how any map could be verified at this point, given lack of details or points of reference in the books.

Comment: [Fanmap](http://i.imgur.com/P7cWb5D.png)

Comment: @Valorum That should be an answer. That's either a fantastic basis for any further, more detailed map (if any details will be revealed in the future) or the best we can get (if otherwise).